# What does the .dup mean in seeds.rb in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
 user = User.find_or_create_by_email 
:name => ENV['ADMIN_NAME'].dup, 
:email => ENV['ADMIN_EMAIL'].dup, 
:password => ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD'].dup, 
:password_confirmation => ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD'].dup
```

This is a part of my simple seeds.rb. Its created by the rails composer.
I know what it does, but i cant find any information for the .dup.

Any information for that?

best regards
denym

Comment: dup is defined on Object: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.dup` is a Ruby method. It's not specific to Rails. Check out the [Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) for more information.

You already know that running `.dup` on an object creates a duplicate of that object. However, you'll often see `.clone` and `.dup` invoked in the same breath. According to the docs:

> In general, clone and dup may have different semantics in descendent classes. While clone is used to duplicate an object, including its internal state, dup typically uses the class of the descendent object to create the new instance.

It may be outside the scope of your post, but here are two examples that might help you understand the difference between `.dup` and `.clone`:

```
o = Object.new
def o.foo
  'bar'
end

o.dup.foo   #=> raises NoMethodError
o.clone.foo #=> returns 'bar'


class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end
foo = Foo.new
foo.freeze

foo.dup.bar = 'baz'   # returns 'baz'
foo.clone.bar = 'baz' # raises RuntimeError
```

As you can see, in the scope of your `seeds.rb`, there's really no distinction between `.dup` and `.clone` (since all you're doing is running a lookup off a string duplicated from you environment globals). However, if you were to run object methods off those duplicated strings, things *might* be behave differently depending on whether you use `.dup` or `.clone`.

Answer (score 0):

it just duplicates the object.

> Produces a shallow copy of obj—the instance variables of obj are
>   copied, but not the objects they reference. dup copies the tainted
>   state of obj. See also the discussion under Object#clone. In general,
>   clone and dup may have different semantics in descendant classes.
>   While clone is used to duplicate an object, including its internal
>   state, dup typically uses the class of the descendant object to create
>   the new instance.

[Object#dup → an_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup)